# Reportlab 3.5 diacritic's in text are mispositioned for certain fonts (Junicode)

Tags: python, python-3.x, reportlab

I'm creating a parser in python3.7 that takes xml files as input and creates PDF files as output. I am using reportlab 3.5 and everything is working except one thing. The text I am parsing uses a certain font called "Junicode". The font is used properly except that the diacritics (the letters that should go above another letter, like "´" goes over "e" like this é) are shifted to the right. One example here:

[image: Word with the diacritic shifted.]

I am using SimpleDocTemplate and the text goes into a table. I simplified the code a little:

```
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Junicode', './fonts/Junicode.ttf'))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('JunicodeBd', './fonts/Junicode-Bold.ttf'))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('JunicodeBI', './fonts/Junicode-BoldItalic.ttf'))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('JunicodeIt', './fonts/Junicode-Italic.ttf'))

document = SimpleDocTemplate("output_pdf/" + os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(imgfile))[0] + ".pdf",
                                             pagesize=self.canvas_size,
                                             rightMargin=Helpers.mm_to_pts(self.margin_right),
                                             leftMargin=Helpers.mm_to_pts(self.margin_left),
                                             topMargin=Helpers.mm_to_pts(self.margin_top),
                                             bottomMargin=Helpers.mm_to_pts(self.margin_bottom))

frame = Frame(document.leftMargin, document.bottomMargin, document.width, document.height)

text_template = PageTemplate(id='textpage', frames=[frame], onPage=self.__draw_text_page)

document.addPageTemplates([text_template])

page_flow = [some_other_stuff , NextPageTemplate('textpage'), PageBreak()]

[... code to get line from xml]

table_data.append(['', line])

[...]

table_styles = [('ALIGN', (0, 0), (0, -1), 'RIGHT'),
                                ('ALIGN', (2, 0), (2, -1), 'RIGHT'),
                                ('SIZE', (0, 0), (-1, -1), self.font_size),
                                ('FONT', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'Junicode'),
                                ('VALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'MIDDLE'), ]

table = Table(table_data, rowHeights=self.table_row_height)

table.setStyle(TableStyle(table_styles))

page_flow.append(table)

document.build(page_flow)
```

I am trying to get the diacritics above the letters, f.e. in the image above, i'd like the 90-degree tilted ":" to be on top of the y.

Does anyone know where this is coming from and if there is a solution for it?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

I managed to solve the issue by editing the font with FontForge. I transformed the x position of the diacritics to a negative value, thus positioning them properly. For capital letters I had to increase the y value too, so I created additional diacritics (on places in the font where no letter was set) with increased y values and replaced the old ones with new ones if a capital letter is in front of it.